# Azure data factory Send custom event to EventGrid using Web activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-eventgrid

I am going to send a custom event to EventGrid Custom topic , through ADF using web activity .

in the header I use

aeg-sas-key , and then the value is the key of the eventGrid

body is something like this

[{
"id": "1807",
"eventType": "recordInserted",
"subject": "myapp/vehicles/motorcycles",
"eventTime": "2017-08-10T21:03:07+00:00",
"data": {
"make": "test",
"model": "test"
},
"dataVersion": "1.0"
}]

however , I got the error

[image]

and one has experience or idea how to do that?

is there anyway to secure the Key ?

Comment: can you try to use an access key as a query parameter? Note, that the value must be in the url-encoded format.

Comment: can you show some example of how to do that?

Comment: have a look at the  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/authenticate-with-access-keys-shared-access-signatures#access-key-as-a-query-parameter

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to use managed identity authentication. Please do the following to achieve this:

1. Create a Data Factory with System Managed Identity
2. Create an Event Grid Topic and copy the topic endpoint into your notepad.
3. Grant the Data Factory access to the Event Grid Topic, by assigning the `EventGrid Data Sender` role.
4. Go to your Data Factory and create a pipeline with the Web Activity
5. Configure the web activity the following way:

Web Activity Config:

- URL: `<your-event-grid-topic-endpoint>` (similar to `https://<your-topic-name>.northeurope-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events`)
- Method: `POST`
- Body: Sample body:

```json
[{
    "id": "@{pipeline().RunId}",
    "eventType": "PipelineFinished",
    "subject": "myapp/pipelines/mydataset",
    "eventTime": "@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 's')}",
    "data": {
        "DataFactory": "@{pipeline().DataFactory}",
        "PipelineName": "@{pipeline().Pipeline}",
        "PipelineGroupId": "@{pipeline().GroupId}",
        "PipelineTriggerId": "@{pipeline().GroupId}",
        "PipelineTriggerName": "@{pipeline().TriggerName}",
        "PipelineTriggerType": "@{pipeline().TriggerType}",
        "PipelineTriggeredByPipelineName": "@{pipeline()?.TriggeredByPipelineName}",
        "PipelineTriggeredByPipelineRunId": "@{pipeline()?.TriggeredByPipelineRunId}"
    },
    "dataVersion": "1.0"
}]
```

- Integration Runtime: Select any runtime
- Authentication: `System Assigned Managed Identity`
- Resource: `https://eventgrid.azure.net/`

Here is an image of the activity and pipeline:
[Data Factory Pipeline Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGVO4.png)